# How to retrieve value based on Key from JSON string in PosgresSql

Tags: json, postgresql

While working on JSON string which is stored in a DB table column as:

lets say table name is t1 and column name is data:

data column stores json string as:

```json
[{"K":"V"}]
```

Below is my query to get the Value based on Key:

```
select Value ->> 'Value'
from json_array_elements(select data from t1) Key
where Key->>'Key'='K';
```

on execution, it gives me syntax error.

Tried all the possible way to fix this but finally need help.

----Edit This is how I got the required result------

1. create a table:

   CREATE TABLE t1 (
   id int,
   data  json
   );
2. Insert data into t1 table:

insert into t1 values

```
(1,'[{"K":"V"}]'),
(2,'[{"loadShortCut_AutoText":"both"}]'),
(3,'[{"P":"R"}]');
```

3. Below query to get the output:

   select row, row->>'loadShortCut_AutoText' as value
   from t1, json_array_elements (t1.data) as row
   WHERE t1.id=2;
4. Output:

   {"loadShortCut_AutoText":"both"}    both

Comment: "it gives me syntax error", could you please share the error message? (in plain text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try this :

```
select row->>'K' as value
from t1, json_array_elements (data) as row
WHERE row->>'K' is not null
```

This will return data only if the key `'K'` exists

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/q7tn6rVl)

Answer (score 0):

`json_array_elements()` returns one row per array element which again is a JSON value. To access the value from that element you need to use `->> 'K'`

A `select` statement can not be passed as a parameter. You need to put the source table into the "main" FROM clause:

```
select e.item ->> 'K' as value
from t1 
   cross join json_array_elements(t1.data) as e(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you may use [jsonb_path_query_array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to query direct the json array (cast of the `json` column  to `jsonb` is required)

```
select
id, data,
(jsonb_path_query_array(t1.data::jsonb, '$[*]?(exists (@."K"))'::jsonpath) -> 0) #>> '{K}'::text[] AS k_value
from t1
```

The JSON path `$[*]?(exists (@."K"))` select all array element that contains the key `"K"` than takes the first such `-> 0` and extracts the value of it  `#>> '{K}'::text[]`.

The advantage of this approach is that it works also for JSON arrays with duplicit data (id=4) and `null` values (id=6) as illustrated on the sample output

```
id|data                   |k_value|
--+-----------------------+-------+
 1|[{"K":"V"}]            |V      |
 2|[{"K":"V"},{"A":"B"}]  |V      |
 3|[{"Z":"V"},{"A":"B"}]  |       |
 4|[{"K":"V"},{"K":"B"}]  |V      |
 5|[{"Z":"V"},{"K":"B"}]  |B      |
 6|[{"Z":"V"},{"K": null}]|       |
```